# Implement an image library with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a few models(`Article, Category`) that all have pictures. The paperclip logic for the picture is extracted at a class `ContentPicture`.

When uploading a picture to Article I would like to select from the already existing ContentPictures or to upload a new one. Does anyone know for gem that could handle the image library **"view already uploaded, select or upload a new one"?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a gem with such focused purpose, and I doubt it exists but you can write you own implementation using Imagemagick [here is the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/), and this is a gem that wraps that API for Ruby: [minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).

If you do have the time you could write your solution for your task at hand, test it and then try and extract it to a gem and make it open source.
That will help you a lot in getting better at ruby and Rails, plus you will be able to contribute back to OS (that is a great way to get noticed by good employers).